# Cohomology group of a torus with g holes

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I have to compute the cohomology groups of a torus with g holes (the Riemann surface of genus g).
first I have computed the cohomology of a Torus with 3 holes in the following way:
I pick a covering $\{U,V \}$ so that $U,V$ look like a pants, cutting suitably the torus, and then by Mayer-Vietoris I computed the cohomology group.

But how I can generalize it to a torus with g holes?

The exercice continues asking:

1. Compute  the cohomology groups of a torus with g holes minus n point?
2. Compute  the cohomology groups of a torus with g holes minus n small open disc pairwise disjoint.

How could I proceed with this two point?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you next compute the cohomology of a torus minus two points, and a cylinder. Let me draw a schematic picture of a 3-holed torus:

()()()

Now I can make a cut across the 4th hole:

()()(|)

and the result, on the right, is a cylinder; on the left, by retracting the "arms" of the rightmost parenthesis, I get a 2-hole torus minus two points.

If you knew the cohomology of the twice-punctured 2-holed torus, you could use MV to find the 3-holed torus cohomology.

So the idea here is to use induction:

1. Find cohomology of a torus and a twice-punctured torus.
2. Find cohomology of a cylinder.
3. Use MV to find cohomology of 2-holed torus
4. Carefully figure out cohomoloyg of twice-punctured 2-holed torus
5. Use MV to find cohomology of 3-holed torus
6. Carefully figure out cohomology of twice-punctured 3-holed torus
7. ...

For the twice-punctured 2-holed torus, you can also use MV: take the 2-holed torus $S$ with points $P$ and $Q$ to be removed. Let $A$ and $B$ be small disks containing $P$ and $Q$ repectively. Let $U = S - \{P, Q\}$, $V = A \cup B$, and apply MV to $(S, U, V)$.

(The same reasoning applies to a many-punctured k-holed torus. )

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the first step...Why if you cut a 3-holed torus in the 3th hole, you find in the left a 2-holed torus minus two point?

Comment: Think of a three-hole torus as a sphere with three "handles" glued on. Cut off part of one handle -- the part your hand wraps around -- and you've got a cylinder; what's left is a sphere with two handles and two little "stubs" sticking up. Retract those stubs towards the sphere, and you end up with two little holes in the sphere-surface. Now shrink those holes down and you end up with two "punctures" in the sphere-surface.